# Compile VSCode extension with webpack now failing after 2 years of previously compiling without issue

Tags: visual-studio-code, webpack

I have come to recompile a VSCode extension and it is now failing with this error:
[image]

I am not using wontache (seems to be a mustache module) in my code but it is being used by another package that I am making use of and which I did upgrade to prior to this compile attempt.

I then tried updating node to V18 and Webpack to a more recent version but the error continues.

I am at a loss as to how to resolve this error. Hoping for some inspiration!
I don't know which files to provide to help identify the solution.
However this is the webpack.config.js as a starter:

```
"use strict";

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
const path = require("path");

/**@type {import('webpack').Configuration}*/
const config = {
  target: "node", // vscode extensions run in a Node.js-context

  entry: "./src/extension.ts", // the entry point of this extension, 
  output: {
    // the bundle is stored in the 'dist' folder (check package.json) 
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "extension.js",
    libraryTarget: "commonjs2",
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: "../[resource-path]",
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  externals: {
    vscode: "commonjs vscode", // the vscode-module is created on-the-fly and must be excluded. Add other modules that cannot be webpack'ed, 
    keytar: "commonjs keytar",
  },

  stats: {
    // Ignore warnings
    warnings: false,
  },
  resolve: {
    // support reading TypeScript and JavaScript files, 
    extensions: [".ts", ".js"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "ts-loader",
            options: {
              compilerOptions: {
                module: "es6", // override `tsconfig.json` so that TypeScript emits native JavaScript modules.
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
module.exports = config;
```

Comment: "_another package that I am making use of and which I did upgrade to prior to this compile attempt_" what package was it? What version constraint had you specified prior, what exact version did you have installed prior, and what did you change the version constraint to, and what exact version do you have installed now?

Comment: I was getting the error with Node V16 . I upgrade to node V18 and webpack-cli V5.0.1 and webpack V5.76.1. and the problem persisted. the package which is making use of wontache is zowe/imperative which I had upgrade as part of another project to V5.9.3

Comment: Where I am struggling is the error message:

ERROR in ./node_modules/wontache/module.js 1:0   

Module parse failed: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' (1:0)  

You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.

Comment: I repeat: "_What version constraint had you specified prior what exact version did you have installed prior, and what did you change the version constraint to_" What exact NodeJS version were you using before?

Comment: as I said I do not know what version of zowe was installed previously.
All I am asking for help on is a better explanation of the error message being presented..       
ERROR in ./node_modules/wontache/module.js 1:0             
and in particular this line             
Module parse failed: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' (1:0)      
 
and the final message:            
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.

Comment: I guess my question might be ... 
why would I need to be concerned about a module residing in node_modules that I am not myself making use of but which causes the error when I try to compile with Webpack. 
qhen The rules: statement in webpack.config.ts contains an  exclude: /node_modules/

Answer (score 0):

This problem was resolved by adding this rule to webpack.config.js.

```
rules: [
    {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: /wontache/,
        type: "javascript/auto", 
    }
]
```